# sed word boundaries: replace command macros with the commands

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I inherited a body of code where "command macros" are used in place of the underlying command to be run, e.g., `$TR` is used in place of `tr`.  I want to use `sed` to convert the command macros back to the shell commands they refer to.  The problem is with word boundaries:

```
$ echo '$TR $TRUE $TRUNCATE "$TR ($TR' | sed s/\$TR/tr/g
tr trUE trUNCATE "tr (tr
```

is clearly wrong.  However, when I try to use `\b` to set word boundaries for translation, that also doesn't work:

```
$ echo '$TR $TRUE $TRUNCATE "$TR ($TR' | sed s/\$TR\b/tr/g
$TR $TRUE $TRUNCATE "$TR ($TR
```

Searching in reverse order by macro length (i.e., first replacing `$TRUNCATE`, then `$TRUE`, then `$TR`) isn't a complete solution because there are also things such as `$TS $TS_FORMAT` where only the stand-alone `$TS` is to be converted to `ts`.

Is there a reason the `\b` word boundary tag isn't working here?  What do I need to do to fix this?

```
$ sed --version
sed (GNU sed) 4.7
Packaged by Debian
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Jay Fenlason, Tom Lord, Ken Pizzini,
Paolo Bonzini, Jim Meyering, and Assaf Gordon.
GNU sed home page: <https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/>.
General help using GNU software: <https://www.gnu.org/gethelp/>.
E-mail bug reports to: <bug-sed@gnu.org>.
```

---

**EDIT**

The file where the command macros are defined includes fully-qualified filenames for all of the commands being replaced, even when an FQFN is not appropriate (e.g., `$TRUE` is defined as `/usr/bin/true` while `type true` returns `true is a shell builtin`).  This causes an on-disk file to be run when `$TRUE` is referenced, so using the command macro (in this case) is a significant performance hit.

The objective is to update the files in the code base so the command macros can go away, removed from the `source`d file where they are defined, so future readers and maintainers of the code don't have to deal with the command macros at all.

Comment: @steeldriver Please make your comment an answer so I can accept it. Thank you!

Comment: What should the output look like if, for example, `TRUE` and `TRUNCATE` are not set? Should it be `tr $TRUE $TRUNCATE "tr (tr` or `tr   "tr (tr` or something else? Please [edit] your question to show the expected output for the case where some variables are not set and the output for the case where they ARE set but you only want the `$TR`s to be converted (which you allude to might be a use-case with `there are also things such as $TS $TS_FORMAT where only the stand-alone $TS is to be converted to ts`).

Comment: It's also not clear if you want to replace `$TR` with a specific string, like you're trying to do with `'s/$TR/tr/'`, or if you want to replace `$TR` with whatever value the variable `TR` has in the environment like if you had `'s/$TR/'"$TR"'/'` so please also [edit] your question to clarify that too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since your sed expression is unquoted, your shell is likely converting `\b` to plain `b`. For example in bash:

```
set -x

$ echo '$TR $TRUE $TRUNCATE "$TR ($TR' | sed s/\$TR\b/tr/g
+ sed 's/$TRb/tr/g'
+ echo '$TR $TRUE $TRUNCATE "$TR ($TR'
$TR $TRUE $TRUNCATE "$TR ($TR
```

whereas

```
$ echo '$TR $TRUE $TRUNCATE "$TR ($TR' | sed 's/\$TR\b/tr/g'
+ sed 's/\$TR\b/tr/g'
+ echo '$TR $TRUE $TRUNCATE "$TR ($TR'
tr $TRUE $TRUNCATE "tr (tr
```

---

However I question the suitability of sed for this task - perhaps consider something like `envsubst` ex.

```
$ echo '$TR $TRUE $TRUNCATE "$TR ($TR' | env TR=tr TRUE=true TRUNCATE=truncate envsubst
tr true truncate "tr (tr
```

Comment: Oooh, I didn't know about `envsubst`, nice! But can it be used on files? The OP has inherited a code base, so presumably, they need to run the command on a bunch of files, could you wrangle `envsubst` into helping there?

Comment: @terdon AFAIK `envsubst` is strictly stdin-stdout. TBH I'm not even sure `envsubst` is appropriate - we'd need to know more about the OP's "command macros".

Comment: @terdon you can always do `envsubst < file` like with any command. I don't think you can use `envsubst` for this though since the OP said `there are also things such as $TS $TS_FORMAT where only the stand-alone $TS is to be converted to ts` which I THINK means they want to choose which specific variable to change.

Comment: @EdMorton you can *kind of* do that using the (IMHO poorly documented) `SHELL-FORMAT` argument ex. `echo '$TS and $TS_X but not $TS_FORMAT' | TS=foo TS_X=bar envsubst '$TS $TS_X'`

Answer (score 1):

For a portable solution, you could use `perl` (where GNU `sed` copied `\b` from):

```
perl -pe 's/\$(?|(TR|TRUE|TRUNCATE|TS)\b|\{((?1))\})/\L$1/g'
```

The `\L` to lower-case what follows in the replacement actually comes from `ex`/`vi`. It's also available in the GNU implementation of `sed` but otherwise not standard nor portable across other `sed` implementations.

- `(?1)` recalls the regex enclosed in the first pair of bare parenthesis and is used here so as not to have to repeat the `(TR|TRUE|TRUNCATE|TS)` in the part of the alternation that matches the `${VAR}` variant.
- `(?|...)` is the *branch reset* version of `(?:...)`. The main difference is that in `(a(x)|b(y))`, what is matched by `x` ends up `$2`, by `y` in `$3` and the enclosing `(...)` in `$1`; with `(?:a(x)|b(y))`, `x` -> `$1`, `y` -> `$2`, `(?:...)` does *grouping* but not *capturing*, and in `(?|a(x)|b(y))`, what is matched by either `x` or `y` ends up in `$1`.

With GNU `sed`, you can do:

```
vars='(TR|TRUE|TRUNCATE|TS)'
sed -E "s/\\\$($vars\>|\{$vars\})/\L\2\3/g"
```

Here using `\>` (also from `ex`/`vi`) rather than perl-style `\b` for consistency with the other `\L` ex-ism, but `\b` would work just the same here.